# Django: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, referer: http://xxx

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, internal-server-error

I've been wondering why when I set the settings.py of my django project 'arvindemo' debug = False and deploy it on Apache with mod_wsgi, I got the 500 Internal Server Error.

Env:
Django 1.4.0
Python 2.7.2
mod_wsgi 2.8
OS centOS

Here is the recap：
Visit the homepage, go to sub page A/B/C/D, and fill some forms, then submit it to the Apache server. Once click 'submit' button, I will get the '500 Internal Server Error', and the error_log listed below(Traceback):

"Sorry, I've put the wrong Trackback, here is the really Traceback should be listed":
PS: 
"STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks" = "http://58.215.177.34/Presentation"

```
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250] mod_wsgi (pid=2973): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/web/django/wsgi/django.wsgi'., referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250]   File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__, referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250]     response = self.get_response(request), referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 URLs
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250]   File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response, referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250]   File "/opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception, referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250]     return callback(request, **param_dict), referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 URLs
[Tue Apr 10 11:03:15 2012] [error] [client 122.198.133.250] TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, referer: STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks
```

[Please replace 'STACKOVERFLOW DON'T LET ME PUT MORE THAN 2 hyperlinks' with 'http://58.215.177.34/Presentation'] :)

When using django runserver, I set arvindemo.settings debug = True, everything is OK. But things changed once I set debug = False.

Here is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import datetime, string
from user_info.models import *
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
import settings
def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello girl")

def helpPage(request):
    return render_to_response('kktHelp.html')

def server_error(request, template_name='500.html'):
    return render_to_response(template_name,
            context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    )

def page404(request):
    return render_to_response('404.html')

def submitPage(request):
    post = request.POST
    Mall = 'goodsName'
    Contest = 'ojs'
    Presentation = 'addr'
    WeatherReport = 'city'
    Habit = 'task'
    if Mall in post:
            return submitMall(request)
    elif Contest in post:
            return submitContest(request)
    elif Presentation in post:
            return submitPresentation(request)
    elif Habit in post:
            return submitHabit(request)
    elif WeatherReport in post:
            return submitWeather(request)
    else:
            return HttpResponse(request.POST)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('404')
def submitXXX():
  .....
def xxxx():
....
```

Here comes the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from views import *
from django.conf import settings

handler500 = 'server_error'
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),  # hello world
    url(r'^$', homePage),
    url(r'^time/$', getTime),
    url(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hoursAhead),
    url(r'^Ttime/$', templateGetTime),
    url(r'^Mall$', templateMall),
    url(r'^Contest$', templateContest),
    url(r'^Presentation$', templatePresentation),
url(r'^Habit$', templateHabit),
url(r'^Weather$', templateWeather),
url(r'^Help$', helpPage),
url(r'^404$', page404),
url(r'^500$', server_error),
url(r'^submitPage$', submitPage),
url(r'^submitMall$', submitMall),
url(r'^submitContest$', submitContest),
url(r'^submitPresentation$', submitPresentation),
url(r'^submitHabit$', submitHabit),
url(r'^submitWeather$', submitWeather),
url(r'^terms$', terms),
url(r'^privacy$', privacy),
url(r'^thanks$', thanks),
url(r'^about$', about),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.STATICFILES_DIRS}),
)
```

I'm sure there is no syntax error in my django project，cause when I use django runserver， everything is fine.

Anyone can help ?

Best regards

Comment: All of this text needs to be shortened to the relevant information. I would like to see a snippet of your settings.py as it is when the crash happens. Also, since you know the exact URL that is causing the crash, the relevant url info should be "Presentation", along with the "templatePresentation" view. Need to see that view (not the other stuff).

Comment: Actually, the problem occured not only in "Presentation", when I visit other sites, the problem still there(Here is the recap： Visit the homepage, go to sub page A/B/C/D, and fill some forms, then submit it to the Apache server. Once click 'submit' button, I will get the '500 Internal Server Error'), the "500 page" occured when I submit forms, and it's relevant views is "submitPage", and I think the exact URL that is causing the crash is "http://58.215.177.34/submitPage". Now here is the snippet of my setting:

Comment: Without seeing a proper full traceback of the crash and knowing what part of your code is crashing, there really isn't much any of us can do to help. If you are confident that the crash is occurring in your `submitPage` view, then I would suggest putting print statements all over it to investigate the values, and check the output in your development server output.

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you consistently misspell False as Flase.  Are you spelling it correctly in the settings file?

Comment: Sorry，it's the correct ‘False’ in the settings file ：）， I think its other reason resault in the error